# Multiple Onclick Events - 1 of 2 Events Working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have put some buttons in a div called "buttons", separate from the map.
I am trying to do two things when a user clicks a button:

1. Centering and zooming a google map - **working**.
2. Displaying text in the div "address" - not working

Button HTML:

```
<button id="Zoom">Zoom1</button>
```

Declaring the "address" `div` in JavaScript:

```
var address = [];
```

Event JavaScript:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('sofZoom'), 'click', function () {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.67,23.45));
    map.setZoom(15);
    address.document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = 'textcontent'
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var address = []` creates a local variable called "address" and assign an array to it. It has absolutely nothing to do with any HTML element.

`address.document` tries to access the `document` property of that array. There is no such property, so trying to call `address.document.getElementById` throws an error.

`document` is a global. Just use it directly.

---

Remove this line.

> ```
> var address = [];
> ```

Replace this line:

> ```
> address.document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = 'textcontent'
> ```

with:

```
document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = 'textcontent'
```

Comment: A precise and educational answer. Thank you!